# How to divide the below line in python?

Tags: python, python-2.x, pep8

```
comm_ip_addr_one, comm_ip_addr_two, mac_addr_one, mac_addr_two =   compute_ip_address()
```

Currently it is more than 80 characters in a line.

When I gave the function name in next line it is invalid syntax.

Please suggest some ways i can split?

Comment: "*Currently it is more than 80 characters in a line.*" - and you're still using a VT100 from 1978 :(

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler: [PEP8 is a bitch](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length).

Comment: @ShadowRanger - "For code maintained exclusively or primarily by a team that can reach agreement on this issue, it is okay to increase the nominal line length..." [They're more what you'd call "guidelines."](https://11tx7b411ycc3zja3v2vhqz9-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Productivity-methods-.jpg)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Yeah. Most teams I know of use PEP8, but they're a bit more flexible on line lengths than the PEP8 official limit.

Answer (score 4):

Parens make the `tuple` unpacking explicit and allow you to split the variables being assigned to:

```
(comm_ip_addr_one, comm_ip_addr_two,
 mac_addr_one, mac_addr_two) = compute_ip_address()
```

Or you can use a line continuation character to allow the function call on the next line:

```
comm_ip_addr_one, comm_ip_addr_two, mac_addr_one, mac_addr_two = \
        compute_ip_address()
```